# Confusing behaviour with intents in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I call GooglePlay from my app through an intent and again after I kill my own app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String sModule = "market://search?q=pub:mycompany";
intent.setData(Uri.parse(sModule));
startActivity(intent);

finish();
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

`Task manager` shows, that only `GooglePlay` is running. My app isn't there anymore.

So my focus is `GooglePlay` at the moment. When going to the Desktop through the Home-Button and calling my App again it directs me to GooglePlay again.

Why is that? How can I call GooglePlay from my app independently?

I expected that when starting my app again, which I had previously killed, it would start my app and not focus on google play.

Comment: What is your exact requirement? Define in more words.

Comment: I expected, that when starting my app again, which I before killed, it will start my app and not focus on google play.

Comment: You are trying to send direct intent without any situation/action?

Comment: This is only simplified showcase for my bigger problem. But do you understand my confusing situation ?

Comment: android:excludeFromRecents="true"  android:noHistory="true" declare this in that activity tag in manifest from where you are sending intent.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds interesting. Now I am not sure with following. I call other intents from my app with own Activities. Will your solution still allows me using my intents with my activities and activityresults ?

Comment: yes it wont affect that, you can call as many intents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keyword is "launchMode" and "task".
this type of problems are so annoying and much complicated in android.
but this time you can try this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String sModule = "market://search?q=pub:mycompany";
intent.setData(Uri.parse(sModule));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);

finish();
```

if u cant solve, try combine another flags with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
cheers!

Comment: Perfect, it works. Thats what I exactly searched for. "NEW TASK".